# How to add editable JComboBox and Button on same Frame..?

Tags: swing, jtable, jbutton, jcombobox

I have created a JTable with 5 columns in it .I want the sixth column to have all cells as JComboBox from where an user can select his choice and the change will get appended in databasefor which i need a button on whose action i can fire the query to my database. So please please let me know how to add JComboBox and ButTon on JFrame...?? I am very new to Swings so do let me know how to get this donea detailed explanation about the same will be very thankful...!!! Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: You start by writing in English instead of using some SMS-like language full of abbreviations and lacking capital letters. If you put some effort in your question, we might want to put some effort in our answers. To get you started, take a look at the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Comment: you can edit your question with this improved version

Comment: Ok fine i hope i get an improved version of answer also ..!!!

Comment: there is no way around reading a basic textbook/tutorial on Swing, f.i. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html has a chapter _How to use JTable_

Comment: BTW: sticky question or exclamation marks might be considered shouting - not exactly a nice thingy to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

How to add `JComboBox` and `JButton` on a `JFrame` is rather trivial. Linking this question to the first part of your question with the table is something I did not manage. But for the part I did understand, you can have something like

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );

JPanel contents = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

JComboBox comboBox = createComboBox();
contents.add( comboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER );

JButton button = createButton();
contents.add( button, BorderLayout.EASTH );

frame.add( contents );

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

The code illustrates how to add a combobox and a button. Note that I opted for the very simple `BorderLayout`. Other layouts are certainly possible, but it all depends on the requirements of your layout.